# log10() performance on Visual Studio 2015 a lot slower than Visual Studio 2013 for x86

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

We have ported a VS2013 C++/MFC application to VS2015 and are having some rather disturbing issues with the performance and code generated by the VS2015 compiler.

Note this is for x86.

It is magnitudes slower on log10() calls. When profiling a Release build using CPU sampling, we see that these calls take up a lot more time than they did before. Going from e.g. 49 samples on the same run for VS2013 to a whopping 7545 samples for the same run in VS2015. This means this function goes from 0.6% of CPU load to 50% for the application in question.

In VS2013 profiler shows:

```
Function Name   Inclusive Samples   Exclusive Samples   Inclusive Samples % Exclusive Samples %
__libm_sse2_log10   49  49  0.61    0.61
```

In VS2015 profiler shows:

```
Function Name   Inclusive Samples   Exclusive Samples   Inclusive Samples % Exclusive Samples %
___sse2_log102  7,545   7,545   50.43   50.43
```

Why a different function name?

We have looked briefly at the generated assembly for log10. On VS2013 this forwards to `disp_pentium4.inc` and `log10_pentium4.asm`. On VS2015 this is different. It seems VS2015 goes back to `__libm_sse2_log10` in Debug.

Could the `__sse2_log102` be the cause of this performance difference alone? We have checked that results output from functions calling these are within expected floating point differences.

We are compiling with target v140_xp and have the following compile options:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /MP /GS- /GL /analyze- /W4 /wd"4510" /wd"4610" /Zc:wchar_t /Z7 /Gm- /Ox /Ob2 /Zc:inline /fp:fast /D "WINVER=0x0501" /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_USING_V110_SDK71_" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR /arch:SSE2 /Gd /Oy /Oi /MT
```

Also shown here when viewing properties:

[image: Optimization]

[image: Code generation]

All project settings are the same for both VS2013 and VS2015. Note we are using SSE2 and have floating point model set to fast.

Has anyone encountered the same issue and know how to fix this?

Comment: One thing which comes to mind is that Microsoft has substantially rewritten their libraries, cf. [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/09/25/rejuvenating-the-microsoft-c-c-compiler.aspx), including their math lib. The rewrite probably falls between the two versions you compare.

Comment: Everything points towards the "__sse2_log102" implementation in VS2015 is the cause, it is way slower than the old implementation. If we replace the call to "log10()" with a call to ippsLog10_64f_A53 this performance regression is removed.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thanks, yes we were aware of this since the port we did had issues with floating point to string formatting, which has also been completely rewritten.

Comment: I just tested and my VS2015 used `___libm_sse2_log10` in release. I'm not sure I reproduced your exact configuration, but I copied at least all the settings in your screenshots.

Comment: And you forgot to mention that you use x86. This makes a huge difference.

Comment: Sorry added this to title and the text.

Comment: If you can provide a minimal repro and open a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio), we would like to investigate.  (I tried to fabricate a repro from your problem description but could not.)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis we are working on it but it having issues with profiler not working on the example project etc. In your repo did you use the same compiler settings as mentioned and targeting v140_xp? Did you try putting the log10() inside a template function?

Comment: We have opened a bug on connect for this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1900541/log10-performance-on-visual-studio-2015-a-lot-slower-than-visual-studio-2013-for-x86

Comment: log is also showing up as slow on our profiling as well.

Comment: @jschroedl we are having trouble making a repo for this, if you have the same issues are you able to provide a repo for this issue in some way?

Comment: Ditto - hard to repro. The stat dev that reported this to me says values used were in 0..1 range. Lots of formulae in the prod code. All my simple tests fail to show diff from 2013 timings.

Comment: @jschroedl Thanks for the info, it is the same for the values in our case, they are fractions in the range ]0....1], but also lots of formulae, templates in our prod code.

Answer (score 6):

Here my comment as an answer.

It appears that VS2015 has changed the implementation of `log10` in release builds, where it calls this new `__sse2_log102` function instead of the old `__libm_sse2_log10` and that this new implementation is the cause of a huge performance difference.

The fix for us in this case was to call an implementation available in Intels Performance Primitives (IPP) library. E.g. instead of calling:

```
return log10(v);
```

Call this instead:

```
double result;
ippsLog10_64f_A53(&v, &result, 1);
return result;
```

This resulted in the performance issue to disappear, in fact it was slightly faster using an old IPP 7.0 release. Not all can use and pay for IPP, though, so we hope Microsoft fixes this.

Below is the version of VS2015 that has shown this issue.

[image]